# How to select cells with variety of values in the same column ?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For example,
I have

```
id foo bar
1   1  34
2   1  32
3   2  12
4   2  23    
5   1  53
```

I need to get only two values from `foo` column - 1 and 2(not 1 1 2 2 1)
What sql-request should be ?
Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Nice, but _which_ 1 and 2 do you want to get?  What is the logic for choosing only 2 of those 5 records?

Comment: yes we need more detail please

Comment: if you are not bothered about the result and only want 1&2 without being id specific, you can simply use select distinct foo from tableWhatever

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just to see the variety of numbers

Comment: @jimmy8ball Does`t matter which, if there are 50 ones and 20 threes, I need to get only this two numbers - 1, 3. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want:

```
 Select * FROM * WHERE foo IN (-1, 2)
```

or
     `SELECT id, if(foo = 1, 1, -1), bar FROM...`

Just guessing,  need some extra information.